# Why Apollo GraphQL query is not working in NextJs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphql, apollo-client

Using Nextjs, I am trying to use Apollo Client to have a query with variables inside one of my nested components that I'll show you how by making a comprehensible though small example of it;

First of all, this is the general arrangement of my project's directories:

[image: general arrangement of all directories]

The problem is inside client directory that I'll explain to you;

The main page of the client directory uses ApolloProvider which is:

```
"use client";

import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";
import MainPageContainer from "./components/MainPageContainer";

function Homepage() {
  const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: "http://localhost:5000/graphql",
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <MainPageContainer />
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

export default Homepage;
```

Inside the MainPageContainer component mentioned above, I have my nested components generating my app's Front-end, and briefly speaking, the error is rooted in my Header Component which contains the problematic query in question;

This is the Header component:

```
import SearchBox from "./SearchBox";

function Header() {
  return (
    <header>
      <SearchBox />
    </header>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

We are getting closer to the problem here, the SearchBox component contains:

```
"use client";

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { FormEvent, useState } from "react";
function SearchBox() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const router = useRouter();
  const handleSubmit = (e: 
FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!input) return;
    router.push(`/search?term=${input}`);
  };
  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    >
      <input
        type="text"
        value={input}
        onChange={(e) => 
setInput(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button
        type="submit"
      >
        Search
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default SearchBox;
```

Here, when the search button is clicked, the Nextjs Router heads the application to the Search page I defined which would be:

```
import { gql, useQuery } from "@apollo/client";

const SEARCH_QUERY = gql`
  query SearchByKeywords($keywords: String!) {
    searchedResponse(keywords: $keywords) {
      data {
        author
        description
        title
      }
    }
  }
`;

function SearchPage() {

  const test = "ufo";
  const { data, loading, error } = 
    useQuery(SEARCH_QUERY, {
    variables: {
      keywords: test,
    },
  });

  return (
    <div>
      Some data returned by the query, hopefully...
    </div>
  );
}

export default SearchPage;
```

The error is happening from the SearchPage component here, saying this:

[image: the error message]

As you see, the query in SearchPage does not seem to work and I literally have no idea where I'm doing wrong, can you please help me fix it? Thanks in advance, I really need your help...

Comment: This needs more information. Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Judging by the error message, you skipped a step. You need to wrap your project in the `ApolloProvider` https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/get-started#step-4-connect-your-client-to-react

Comment: Are you trying this in the app directory in a file that is not marked `"use client"`?

Comment: @Liam I enhanced the question to make it more comprehendible, can you see what's the problem now?

Comment: @rguarascia.ts I wrapped the whole SearchBox parent component in "use client". Won't that help?

Comment: @phry "use client" is used in it's parent component, SearchBox, where the SearchPage is being imported.

Comment: I don't see you using `SearchPage` as a chold component to `SearchBox` here, so I'm a bit confused. Have you tried to add a "use client" to your `SearchPage` where you get the error?

Comment: @phry `SearchBox` is part of my `Header` component of the main page, containing the search input and the button, and `SearchPage` is the page where the app is routed to when the search button is clicked. And I did use "use client" for `SearchPage` but this error pops up: Invariant Violation: `Could not find "client" in the context or passed in as an option. Wrap the root component in an <ApolloProvider>, or pass an ApolloClient instance in via options.`

Comment: @phry And the reason I didn't use `SearchPage` in `SearchBox` is because the tutorial did so, and the content of it is being rendered as expected, maybe because of `Next Navigation` I guess(?).

Comment: Then you need that "use client" statement there. You get this error message because it tries to use it in a server component, and you cannot use the Apollo hooks there.

Comment: The `Could not find "client" in the context or passed in as an option. Wrap the root component in an <ApolloProvider>, or pass an ApolloClient instance in via options.` is another error. You need to wrap your application in an `ApolloProvider`. To make one thing clear: the app directory is a highly experimental tech preview. You probably have no good reason to look at that right now if you are not a tech lead somewhere. You will be facing problems left and right.

Comment: @phry Thanks for your reply. Since I'm a newbie to NextJS I still don't know how to fix that issue, do you think I should take a NextJS course from ground up? I'm an intermediate ReactJS developer.

Comment: My main point was that the Next app directory was unstable until yesterday, so there is generally very little information that you will find about doing things there right now. That warning though, is because you called an Apollo hook without wrapping your app in an ApolloProvider.